# How to get parent widget color in flutter tree widget?

Tags: flutter, colors, widget, treeview, luminance

I want change a color of a button depending by background color of with:

```
computeLuminance()
```

So, I need to get parent widget located by button and get its color / any that can I calculate difference between the two colors.

```
Color calculateTextColor(Color background) {
    return background.computeLuminance() >= 0.5 ? Colors.black : Colors.white;
  }
```

I need to pass background color as exact parent color widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a parent property ( color ) by referring to it using the `BuildContext`, and the `findAncestorWidgetOfExactType` method like this:

```
   Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return Text(
                "Hello",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: context
                      .findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<Container>()
                      ?.color
                      ?.withGreen(255),
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

As you see in the example, I wrapped the `Text` widget with a `Builder` to give it a new `BuildContext` so I can start searching from it ( not wrapping with the `Builder` widget will make the look-up start from the `BuildContext` of the `build()`, which exclude the current `Widget` tree, which is not what we want ).

Then, starting the lookup with `findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<Container>()`, In my example I have the parent as a `Container` so I set its type as generic.

this will give accessibility to its properties, and get me it the same color.

the `withGreen()` is just to clarify that it works.